# How do I assign each <li> its respective data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I have a list of users in the Parse database. Each user has his/her own rating, but that rating is in a different class since you can't write to the user class unless you are *that* user whose data is being modified. (The rated user's rating should change each time the reviewer submits the review.)

```
var current = Parse.User.current();
var relation = current.relation("FriendRelations");
relation.query().find({
    success: function (results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            $('ul').prepend('<li id = "frienditems"><strong><div id ="friendname">' + results[i].getUsername() + '</div></strong></li>');

            * * //Get friend's rating.
            var Rating = Parse.Object.extend("Rating");
            var query = new Parse.Query(Rating);
            query.equalTo("user", results[i].getUsername());
            query.find({
                success: function (results) {
                    for (var y = 0; y < results.length; y++) {
                        var object = results[y].get("Rating");
                        $("#frienditems").append('<p class="friendrating">' + object + '</p>');
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {}
            }); * * $('#frienditems').prepend('<img class="profilepicture" src="img/profileimg.jpg">');

            $('#friendname').on('click', function () {
                var username = $(this).text();
                var replaced = username.split(' ').join('+');
                window.location = "profile.html?firstname=" + replaced;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

** This part is the most important. Ideally, I would like to be able to do this:

```
var relation = current.relation("FriendRelations");
relation.query().find({
    success: function (results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            $('ul').prepend('<li id = "frienditems"><strong><div id ="friendname">' + results[i].getUsername() + results[i].get("Rating") + '</div></strong></li>');
```

This way, it would be clear that the current list item gets the rating attached to it. But since I can't use the User class to update the rating, it's out of the question.

The problem is essentially that I have two different classes, one with the User and the other with the username and his/her rating. If I append the rating to the list item, Javascript isn't going to know which list item gets what, so it's just all going to be appended to the first one.

Putting a query in a query hasn't helped because of variable scope problems.

What's the best way to solve this problem?

So far it ends up like this, where BigBoss should have 50 appended and John should have 80:

[image]

Instead, it all gets appended to one list item.

Comment: I'm not getting what is your problem?

Comment: Let's say I have an unordered list of users, added through JQUERY, retrieved from the Parse database. I have a separate class of ratings for each user. I want to append the correct rating to the correct list item/user? I updated with a picture.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for this? Or can you provide the arrays/json that is returned for both 'results'?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is coming from your use of the **#frienditems** ID. Your browser will naturally try to match only a single ID, and in your script you are generating multiple ID's.

Without knowing the ins and outs of your script and classes, you could do something along the lines of:

```
$('ul').prepend('<li class="frienditem_'+i+'"><strong><div class="friendname">' + results[i].getUsername() + '</div></strong></li>');
```

and

```
$('.frienditem_'+i).append('<p class="friendrating">' + object + '</p>');
```

This way you are matching a specific class for each generated 'friend'.

Comment: Thanks! The problem I really ended up with is that the first loop completely iterates through before moving onto the second one. So I'm dealing with that now. It should be: get username, get rating, get next username, get next rating, etc. Instead it's "get usernames, get ratings"

Comment: Is it possible to fetch all the usernames, save them locally, then map the ratings to the user object you have, and finally iterate through the 'complete' dataset to create what you need.